# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.robovm.apple.coregraphics.CGRect.getSize() robovm

Tags: libgdx, robovm

I'm unable to build iOS with libgdx / robovm. The application compiles ok, but im receiving this error during its startup:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.robovm.apple.coregraphics.CGRect.getSize()Lorg/robovm/apple/coregraphics/CGSize;
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSApplication.getBounds(IOSApplication.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSApplication.didFinishLaunching(IOSApplication.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSApplication$Delegate.didFinishLaunching(IOSApplication.java)
    at

org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplicationDelegate$ObjCProxy.$cb$application$didFinishLaunchingWithOptions$(Unknown Source)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java)
    at br.com.animvs.ants.ios.AntsIOS.main(AntsIOS.java)
```

**Environment Versions:**

- robovm: 1.0.0-beta-01
- iOS Simulator: 8.0
- libgdx: "1.5.1-SNAPSHOT" and "1.4.1"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I found the answer. Currently, robovm '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' is required to build against libgdx '1.5.1-SNAPSHOT'.</s>

This issue has been fixed, see it on: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2652

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also update your libgdx version to 1.5 in order to use robovm 1.0.0-beta-01